# crackling and popping sounds in almost-new MacBook Pro

Tags: audio, headphones, youtube, speakers

I have a Macbook Pro that I just bought a couple of months or so ago,

MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2020, Four Thunderbolt 3 ports)
OS Catalina 10.16.6

Anyhow recently I noticed that playing Youtube videos and listening to the speakers -- and playing a game -- there's a popping and crackling. I hooked up the headphones and it seems to calm down. Tried playing Apple Music and I don't seem to hear it much there, or at least it's nowhere near as obvious.

I am not sure if this is a software or hardware problem. I saw some stuff on a developer's site that discussed this but I wasn't in a position to understand if they were talking about the same problem and the fixes they proposed made little sense to this relatively non-tech savvy user.

Other people who noted a "popping" seem to associate it with the trackpad, but this isn't what I mean at all -- this is something that happens at a minimum on videos -- though I just switched to ABC News and I see that the sound seems ok...

One fix I read about was to turn the mic volume to zero. I just tried that. Fired up a Youtube video, volume not too high, and I hear random crackles. When this problem appeared before I tried restarting.

Is this something I should just exchange the computer for? Is it a hardware issue with the speakers? I note that Apple seems to have altered the way speakers are set up, they seem to be in the back, though I have no idea if that means anything to the hardware.

Comment: Do you hear this sound when playing videos from sites like Hulu or Vimeo?

Comment: Just tried Hulu. Doesn't seem to happen there.

Comment: Also pulled up a Youtube vid again, seems to have calmed down... but it's still weird.